# What is the most efficent way to measure true ping times?

Tags: linux, networking, ping, low-latency

I have a server in AWS-East-1 (N. Virginia) and I am trying to ping [www.binance.com](http://www.binance.com) whose server is located in AWS Tokyo.

Command: ping [www.binance.com](http://www.binance.com)

I get ping times of 0.5ms which is not true. Possibly, the ping is returning from some nearby router and theoretically even at the speed of light, the return trip should take atleast 75ms.

How do I measure the correct ping latency from my Linux terminal?

Comment: but it also depends on how you know the server is in Tokyo, because a big organization like binance would most likely have multi-region serving for their app front

Comment: Understand that ping only measures ICMP time, but that jas nothing to do with application performance because applications do not use ICMP, but they will use something else, such as TCP or UDP. ICMP is a low-priority protocol, and it is often ignored until a device has time after processing for its primary job. Ping was really designed to report reachability, not to be used for testing application performance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to make this test to check performance of application or network.......

Maybe, you can use other approach:

```
curl -o /dev/null -s -w '%{time_connect}\n' https://www.binance.com
```

It will return the time_connect so maybe it can help you in your analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to measure a round trip delay. It is the delay between the time when your network node request packet is sent and a time when the response packet from remote server arrives back to you. It can be measured by the Wireshark network analyzer. It analyzes a real traffic. **The results are more accurate then from the ICMP protocol (ping) tests.**

### Wireshark usage

1. Ensure you have not opened any connection to your destination server (e.g. [www.binance.com](http://www.binance.com)). Check all tabs in your web browser(s).
2. Find out the IP address of your destination server: `dig +short www.binance.com` and note all found addresses.
3. Install the Wireshark application if it is not installed.
   Start the Wireshark, select correct interface on which the network data will be captured and start the capturing.
4. Open the IP address of page you will measure e.g. [65.9.96.71](http://www.binance.com) in the browser. Refresh the page. It is not problem if error is displayed in browser.
5. Stop the capturing in Wireshark.
6. Put a filter string to the display filter field of the Wireshark. (See below for filter examples.) Press Enter. Only packets which have selected IP address will be displayed.
7. Watch the packet times in second column. Calculate the delay between the request packet and the response one.

Wireshark display filters (each line is one example):

```
ip.addr==65.9.96.71
ip.addr==65.9.96.30 and tcp.port==80
ip.addr==65.9.96.30 and tcp.port==443
```

**Note:**
The Wireshark installation in Linux requires some special steps. Confirm you agree that the Wireshark can be used by all users in system. Add your user to the `wireshark` group and re-login to apply new user setting.

```
usermod -aG wireshark <your_user>
```

### Additional information

You can trace the network path between your client and remote server by `traceroute`. It shows you what nodes (routers) are there.

Verify in which country the destination IP address is situated. Use some IP Whois web page to get details. https://ipwhois.io/